# Conversion of JSON to parquet format using Apache Parquet in C#

Tags: c#, parquet

How can i convert a json file from a mongo db source to a Parquet file using C#?

I have found a library called Parquet.Net but i need something more dynamic. The data i have it is very dynamic and it is dificult to build a schema on that, if you have a solution to this problema please let me know.

```
  var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\NodeJS\Downloads\countries.json");
            List<object> tt = new List<object>();
            var fields = new HashSet<DataField>();

            foreach (var item in file)
            {

                var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(item).ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                 foreach(var t in entity)
                {
                    fields.Add(new DataField(t.Key, t.Value.GetType()));
                        tt.Add(t.Value);
                }
            }

            var schema = new Schema(fields);

            using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("convertJson.parquet"))
            {
                ParquetConvert.Serialize(tt, fileStream,schema);
            }
```

Comment: _if you have a solution to this problem please let me know._ - A solution to **what** problem, exactly?

Comment: I have dynamic data sets and i need to build a schema  dynamically so a i can parse it to a parquet file ? you dont se the title and my description ?

Comment: Yes, I saw the title and description, but no example of a specific problem that you need to solve, just "the data i have it is very dynamic"  and "it is difficult to build a schema". What you need to do is show what your input data looks like, how it is 'dynamic', what your output data should look like, and why what you have tried so far isn't getting you there.

Comment: I think what is meaning is that is he/she gets a data set that is very dynamic he doesn't know what kind of data he/she gets and he use reflection to read the name of the fields of the data object, but the problem is bigger when he/she gets nested array or a object that is not primitive datatype for example Person { Age:12, children:[{amount:1}, {school:true}]} this kind of data is very hard to parse he doesn't know what kind of data the object will have. I think he explained very well , You don't need to be a rocket science to understand what he means here!

Answer (score 3):

You could consider looking into [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.Parquet/) - an open source library, which can convert JSON to Parquet file.

Install Nuget package

> install-package ChoETL.Parquet

Sample code

> using ChoETL;

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("*** Your JSON file ***"))
{
    using (var w = new ChoParquetWriter("*** Your parquet output file ***"))
    {
        w.Write(x);
    }
}
```

For more information, please visit [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=choetl) article.

**Sample fiddle**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fIJIfM

Comment: i noticed it works but my parquet files created in ChoETL from json are much larger than the ones done in pyarrow in python. Any ideas to shrink this?

Comment: missed compression method. Use `.Configure(c => c.CompressionMethod = Parquet.CompressionMethod.Gzip)` on writer to compress the output.

Comment: This is not thread-safe, how do I use it across concurrent threads?